# is it possible to parse json response without root object in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

is it possible to parse json response without root object in extjs4.1.If yes can anybody tell how to do

Thanks

Comment: Why post a 1 line question? At least post the json you're trying to parse, what your store definition is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to not define the root (reader property of proxy). For example, when you have root and total property, the proxy definition looks like the following

```
proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "users.json",  
        reader: {
            type    : 'json',
            root    : 'result.account',
            totalProperty: "result.totalRecords"
        }
    }
```

Without the root (that means there is no totalProperty as well), the definition will look like this

```
proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "users.json",  
        reader: {
            type    : 'json'
        }
    }
```